# Using var and let variables of the same name?

Tags: javascript

Ever since let came out it allowed me to follow stricter naming conventions.However, lets consider the below scenario, would it be valid or is it hacky to do something like this? I am very well aware that the first has function scope and the other block scope.

```
var sample = 'sample';

function fooBar() {
  let sample = 'This is a sample';

  console.log(sample);
}

fooBar();

console.log(sample)
```

Comment: Of course it's valid, just like both declared with `var`. Is hiding globals a good idea? Almost certainly not. And they both have function scope in this case.

Comment: It's not hacky, it's pointless. 1: don't use global state. 2: Use meaningful names. 3: **never** use `var` again.

Comment: @Amit - I'm curious about #3. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @Amit ok I think I dont agree with point 3. I never use globals when I code. This is an example...so the names are ofcourse not meaningful.

Comment: @Asperger There's no reason to use `var` when there's `const` and `let`. They're more communicative, and not susceptible to the problems of `var`.

Comment: @DaveNewton for real? I heared (read) js is getting datatypes by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do here is perfectly valid and is called shadowing. As the name suggests - You have shadowed the global scoped variable ***sample*** with the function scoped variable ***sample***. And by doing that you have restricted yourself to access the global variable without using some special tricks. 
You can still access global variable of the same name inside the function as given below

```
var sample = 'sample';
function fooBar() {
  var sample = 'This is a sample';
  console.log(sample); // 'This is a sample'
  console.log(window.sample); //Sample
  //console.log(this.sample);//Sample. Works only in non strict mode
}
fooBar();
console.log(sample); // 'sample'
```

Moreover, if someone says **never use var** then that little too hard a statement to make. var still has its use. You can have a look at this article by Kyle Simpson here

https://davidwalsh.name/for-and-against-let

Hope this be of some help.

Happy Learning :)
Vatsal

Comment: Hey Vatsal. What about accessing variables in parent functions. I actually dont nest functions but im just curious. If it wasnt part of the window but of another function / object would I call it like this: fn.sample?

Comment: You can either access variables that are in your current function scope or that are in the global window scope. There is no way you can access the variable of your parent function. Scope lookup always starts from innermost function and it stops as soon as it finds the variable. You can only access the global variables using window object but there is no way to lookup/access non global shadowed variables

Comment: I read that blog post by David Walsh and am completely unimpressed by the arguments presented in it.

Answer (score 1):

It's valid.

And since one declaration is outside the function and the other is inside, you could even declare both with `var`:

```js
var sample = 'sample';
function fooBar() {
  var sample = 'This is a sample';
  console.log(sample); // 'This is a sample'
}
fooBar();
console.log(sample); // 'sample'
```